# WTForms FieldList - getting unsorted data

Tags: python, forms, wtforms

I use [WTForms `FieldList`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList) field for lists of fields. It gets the values of these input fields sorted by their names in `form.data`. But I want to get the values in the order they appear in the form. Overriding `process` function is the only solution that I know of. Any ideas on simpler solutions?

Answer (score 0):

So the HTTP spec says the following.

> The parts are sent to the processing agent in the same order the corresponding controls appear in the document stream.

So that takes care of part one. Part two is what can you do. `WTForms` will process anything in the form of a `Multidict` specifically it needs to have a `getlist` method.

The rest depends on what libs you are using. The **Werkzeug** project supplies an `ImmutableOrderedMultiDict.` implementation and there are several that can found be searching the **PyPi** repository or on github(https://github.com/gruns/orderedmultidict).

The last remaining piece is does your web server implementation preserve the forms ordering(i.e. is it strictly compliant with the **W3C** spec?) This part I don't know because I don't know what you are using.